# is the sqllocaldb.msi 2019 for x86 machine

Tags: localdb, mdf

I want to deploy mdf file with version 904 (sqllocaldb2019) on processor x86 but I cant find sqllocaldb 2019 foe x86, what should I do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server LocalDB is only available in x64 edition.